# Using AsynkTask from IntentService for a messaging app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I´m developing a messaging app . Each time the user sends a message , the message   is persisted in the local database and before sending it through an AsynkTask in a POST to the server it verifies if there are other messages with the status of "not sent" in the database  . If there are messages with this status I persist the last message and  create a loop to send  message by message creating an asynk task for each one . If the server responses OK ,the status of the message is changed to "sent" in the database  . If there are no messages with the status "not_sent" , the current message is sent to the server through an asynk task.
The problem is that every time the user sends a message this validation is done and new asynk tasks are created before checking if the first AsynkTask dispatched the others . 
Should I create a service and send all the messages to get dispatched in it ? Or should I call the AsynkTask with a SerialExecutor option ?

Answer (score 0):

you should add another state of 'sending' when a message is being sent to the server (this way the second AsyncTask will no deal with messages that the first AsyncTask is currently sending)

Comment: So , you don´t recommend me to create a service, but what about the SerialExecutor option ?

Answer (score 0):

From API11 AsyncTask use executer per application, so tasks run serially.
Can be a problem with DB synchronization.

As for architecture service is a good choice for a chat application.